# Java Regex , How to get equivalent value of the particular substring using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have following string:

```
mydata ="\nmyName=ram\nmySalaryL=$2,256.00\n";
```

How to get my name and salary values using regex?

Comment: Welcome on SO, have you tried something so far?
You will see that people are really friendly when you respect the rules on:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try using Regex Capture Groups. They are placed in parenthesis and give you access to a matched substring. 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html

A reasonable regex might be:

```
java.util.regex.Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\nmyName=(\w+)\nmySalayL=$((\d{1,3},)*(\d{1,3})\.\d{2}))\n");
java.util.regex.Matcher match = regex.matcher(inputString);

if(match.matches()) {
    String myName = match.group(1);
    String mySalary = match.group(2);
}
```

Please pay attention that capture group 0 is the entire string and matches() needs to be called before accessing the capture groups, because it does the actual regex-matching.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use regular expressions at all! It is enough to split by `\n` character and then by `=` to get those information:

```
String mydata ="\nmyName=ram\nmySalaryL=$2,256.00\n";
String[] arr = mydata.split("\n");
System.out.println(arr[1].split("=")[1]);
System.out.println(arr[2].split("=")[1]);
```

Comment: Actually i have shared just an instance of mydata, but mydata is varchar (10000), it will increase complexity. So im trying regex.

Comment: @tejram Answer is still valid